# RadioButton onCheckedChanged with DataBinding and lambdas

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have a RadioButton:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rdioA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="@{!q.b}"
    android:onCheckedChanged="@{(cb, isChecked) -> {if (isChecked) q.setB(false)}}"
    android:text="AAA"/>
```

The variable 'q' is defined as:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable name="q" type="com.example.Q"/>
</data>
```

The function in Q.java is:

```
public void setB(boolean b) {
    this.b = b;
}
```

The compilation error i get is:

```
/Users/../view_d.xml
Error:(60, 53) Syntax error: extraneous input '=' expecting {<EOF>, '.', '::', '[', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '<<', '>>>', '>>', '<=', '>=', '>', '<', 'instanceof', '==', '!=', '&', '^', '|', '&&', '||', '?', '??'} 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
```

If I use

```
android:onCheckedChanged="@{q::onCheckedChanged}"
```

there is no issue - it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use statements in data binding expressions. This includes curly braces or `if` statements. Use this instead:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rdioA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="@{!q.b}"
    android:onCheckedChanged="@{(cb, isChecked) -> (isChecked) ? q.setB(false) : void}"
    android:text="AAA"/>
```

You can use ternary expressions to replace `if` statements. If you want to do nothing, the `void` keyword can be used to indicate no return value. This works because `onCheckedChanged()` has a `void` return value. If you were binding to a listener that expected a return value like `onLongClick()`, you would use the return type of that listener instead -- `true` or `false` for `onLongClick()`

You should try to avoid using complex logic inside your data binding expressions. The choice to not support statements was to try to limit the complexity of binding expressions.

Comment: That works, Thank you. I have another problem with calling functions of that class (which is of type BaseObservable), so I needed to re-route the call to q.setB() via another class, which is also registered in the layout file. But that's another issue i suppose.